# Implementing offline data storage and synchronization in React Native using react-native-offline and redux-persist

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-form

I am currently working on a **React Native app** where I need to implement offline data storage and synchronization. After researching, I found that the **react-native-offline** and **redux-persist plugins** can help achieve this.

**Here are my specific questions and concerns:**

1. I have started implementing **react-native-offline** and can now detect
   whether the device has an internet connection or not. What should I
   focus on next? Should I proceed with implementing **redux-persist to
   save data locally?**
2. Do I need to use both **react-native-offline** and **redux-persist**
   plugins, or is one of them sufficient for offline data storage and
   synchronization?
3. I'm a bit confused about the concepts of **store**, **reducers**, and **sagas**.
   Do I need to modify all these files to enable offline functionality,
   or is it limited to specific parts of the codebase?
4. Should I consider using a temporary database for storing offline
   data, or can I simply store it directly on the local device using
   **redux-persist**?

I would greatly appreciate any advice or guidance on the recommended approach, the flow of files that need to be modified, and any other considerations when implementing offline data storage and synchronization in an existing React Native app.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: any tutorial would be helpful..